# Discord.js Commands Cooldown

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have some code and I don't fully know how to get a cooldown on it. It needs to be for the whole server, not on persons user id.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'bump',
    description: "This will bump the server",
    execute(message, args){
        const user = message.author;
        var bumpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Time to Bump!')
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .setDescription('Please use the command `!d bump` to bump the server!!!')
        message.channel.send(`Thanks ${user.username} for the bump!!`)
            setTimeout(() => {
              message.channel.send('**PLEASE DO NOT BUMP, UNLESS THE BUMP ROLES HAS BEEN MENTIONED!!**')
            }, 1000)
            setTimeout(() => {
            message.channel.send('<@&821978298938425426>')
            message.channel.send(bumpEmbed)
        }, 7200000)
      }
    }
```

Any youtube vids on learning this would help!

Comment: All I can find are videos that are locked to user ids and none of them made any sense to me.

Comment: Discord.JS has an official guide on how to create cooldowns, [View The Guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns)

Comment: Thats locked to a user id

Comment: Use a server id instead then.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the [discord.js guide example on cooldowns](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns) and replace the parts where it uses `message.author.id` with `message.guild.id` and this should work